# ERROR AL IMPORTAR PAQUETES

Tags: java, packages

Cuando intento compilar la clase principal (CraftMania.java) desde la cmd me dice que no puede importar los paquetes del proyecto (no los encuentra): https://github.com/mcourteaux/CraftMania Se que tiene algo que ver con el classpath pero no se que hacer. **Necesito ayuda porfavor.**

[image: comando a aplicar][image: aplicando el comando][image]

Comment: Sería muy útil que mostrases una foto de la ejecución del comando, para ver las rutas

Comment: Gracias, ahi lo edité.

Comment: Puedes poner el codigo ?

Comment: Creo que esto te servirá: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375179/java-package-does-not-exist-error

Comment: Me lo deja un poco dificil ese enlace YSCGProJ XD, ya me fije ahí gracias, pero no me lo deja muy claro, necesito saber que debo hacer exactamente en este caso. srJJ el codigo esta en el enlace que deje en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido al sitio!.

Como sugerencia, es mejor hacer esa tarea con la ayuda de algún IDE, es que por CMD uno tendría que referenciarle al *classpath* una por una las librerías necesarias de ***LWJGL*** ([Lightweight Java Game Library](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/download.php.html)) y ***[Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com)***, creo son como 11 archivos jar.

Entonces...

- Con Eclipse, solo importas el proyecto 'CraftMania':

> *File > Import > General > Existing Project into Workspace*

- Clic derecho en el nombre del proyecto y agregas las librerias
  ***LWJGL*** y ***Slick2D***:

> *Build Path > Configure Build Path... > Libraries > Add External JARs...*
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

- Lo ultimo es también bastante importante, ese proyecto *CraftMania* tiene un directorio llamado ***natives***; reemplaza su contenido con el de la carpeta ***native*** que se descargó con ***lwjgl-2.9.3*** con el fin de evitar un detestable error `java.lang.LinkageError` (dado porque la version de las librerias 2.9.3 es distinta de la que usaron para compilar este proyecto anteriormente).

Espero haber sido lo mas preciso y descriptivo posible.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, está muy detallado y es esperable de alguien con reputación mayor a mil. ¿Será posible hacerlo también en NetBeans? Cuando voy a "Import Eclipse Project" no lo detecta como proyecto Eclipse. Sinó uso Eclipse.

Comment: En cualquier entorno de desarrollo integrado se puede hacer dicha importación sin ningun problema, ahora, seria tremendamente adecuado si tienes una cuenta GitHub para que simplemente clones el repositorio y lo trabajes sin preocuparte por su estructura.